# Передача делегата на функцию через IPC сервер

Tags: c#, .net

Будет ли нормально функционировать код на сервере, если передавать лямбду по IPC каналу как делегат, при этом код в лямбде может изменяться в зависимости от времени выполнения?

Что имеется ввиду по изменяться во время рантайма:
 так это то, что данная лямбда должна будет управлять неуправляемыми ресурсами, т.е. производить их аллокацию, и удаление в частности.

Comment: А в чем конкретно вы видите проблему?

Comment: Как я думаю, переданная лямбда с захваченными значениями работать не будет на стороне сервера.

Comment: ну надо передавать или готовый к исполнению фрагмент, который в себе уже содержит всё что нужно, или передавать что-то из чего можно этот фрагмент будет собрать на той стороне (типа выражения/дерева выражений)